# REST Request performed by ExtJS store fails

Tags: rest, extjs, store

I am trying to perform a REST request using an ExtJS store using the following code:

```
var myStore = Ext.getStore('MyStore');
myStore .load({
    callback: function(records, operation, success) {
        //Here success is false and records is null even though
        //the server method actually returns a value
    }
});
```

The server side method is executed correctly. I know this cause I debug it with Eclipse. It executes pretty fast and returns a result. 
In spite of this the callback is called many seconds after the server method has terminated and the value of the `success` parameter is `false`. Why so many seconds pass since the end of the server method and the beginning of the callback?

P.S.
Now I have inserted the line `myStore.proxy.setTimeout(3*60*1000);` and it works. But since the server side method only takes 5 or 6 seconds to execute, it shouldn't be necessary to set such a huge timeout!

Comment: Can you check network tab inside developer tools of browser. It can give very clear idea whats going on.

Comment: can you please share your store/proxy definition?